# how customize style materail UI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am trying to customize MUI to that import `makeStyles`

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```

I get this error when try install `npm install @mui/styles`

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: note-app-material-ui@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/styles
npm ERR!   @mui/styles@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:_logs\2022-04-08T15_14_10_234Z-debug-0.log
```

what should I do to customize my design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just can use `inline style` or `sx prop`

```
import { styled } from '@mui/styles';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

const SubmitButton = {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    ...your style
};

<Button
  variant="contained"
  color="secondary"
  type="submit"
  endIcon={<KeyboardArrowRight />}
  style={SubmitButton }
>
  submit
</Button>

/*** OR ***/
/*** use sx prop ***/

<Button
  variant="contained"
  color="secondary"
  type="submit"
  endIcon={<KeyboardArrowRight />}
  sx={SubmitButton}
>
  submit
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

That part of the MUI v5 library is legacy and not compatible with React 18:

> ⚠️ @mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18.

From docs: https://mui.com/styles/basics/

The `makeStyles` API is not where the MUI  team wants to take the product. The new v5 approach is more component based, using **styled components** as well as **utility-based** with the `sx` prop.

Comment: Ok, bro now what should I use to customize my style

Comment: I use `--force` and now it works, and thank you

Comment: I'd use the `styled` API!

Comment: what is the new way `React v18` will support it if you know

Comment: Do you necessarily need to use `makeStyles`??? It will just simply not work with React 18, and going forward they are not going to provide support for it because it is marked as `LEGACY`.

[These are the recommended ways  to customize now](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/).

Comment: No bro it's not important to use `makeStyles` just I needed another solution